# Append an input field to the end of an li element. jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

let's say I enter something into an input field, whatever is typed gets appended to a ul along with another input field.

I can't figure out a way to append the input field. I mean, what I tried added an input at the beginning of the li and adds it over and over again.

```js
$("#add").on("click", function() {

  var i = $("#task").val();
  var time = document.createElement("input");
  time.setAttribute("type", "text");
  $("#task").val("");
  $("ul").append("<li><span>X</span> " + i + " " + "</li>");
  $("ul li").append(time);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input">
  <input type="text" id="task" name="todo" placeholder="Your task">
  <button id="add">Add It</button>
 </div>

 <div id="after"></div>
 
 <ul>
  <li><span>X</span> Code ToDo</li>
  <li><span>X</span> Read two books</li>
  <li><span>X</span> Run</li>  
 </ul>
```

Comment: `$("ul li")` selects all the `li`'s in the list - use the `:last` selector.

Comment: @tymeJV the input field is not getting displayed. Instead [object HTMLInputElement] is getting displayed.

Comment: When I hit "Run Code Snippet" - inputs display for me,.

Comment: what did you mean about "over and over again" do you mean you want to add inputs to all <li> on each click?

Comment: @MamdouhFreelancer that is what I don't want. I have been helped with that.

Comment: So before posting answer see this https://jsfiddle.net/MamdouhFreelancer/vuLhh8yr/

Comment: Hey, this worked thank you. But something is wrong with my browser, the input field is getting displayed in the beginning of the li.

Comment: did you use `direction: rtl;` or floating input to right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.append(li + input)` to avoid `append()` to all `li` on each click

about direction maybe you are using css `direction:rtl;` witch will make input in left side or you are using `float:left;` with inputs.

```js
$("#add").on("click", function() {
  var i = $("#task").val();
  $("#task").val("");
  $("ul").append("<li><span>X</span> " + i + " " + " <input type='text' /></li>");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input">
  <input type="text" id="task" name="todo" placeholder="Your task">
  <button id="add">Add It</button>
</div>

<div id="after"></div>

<ul>
  <li><span>X</span> Code ToDo</li>
  <li><span>X</span> Read two books</li>
  <li><span>X</span> Run</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the input only in the value you `added`? If so:

```
$("#add").on("click", function() {

        var i = $("#task").val();
        var time = document.createElement("input");
        time.setAttribute("type", "text");
        $("#task").val("");
        $("ul").append("<li><span>X</span> " + i + " " + "</li>").append(time); // just moved ".append(time)" to this line
})
```

If you want the input only in the `last li`:

```
$("#add").on("click", function() {

        var i = $("#task").val();
        var time = document.createElement("input");
        time.setAttribute("type", "text");
        $("#task").val("");
        $("ul").append("<li><span>X</span> " + i + " " + "</li>");
        $("ul li:last").append(time);
})
```